# "Simple" sort a nested array using array_multisort or native PHP functions instead of my own foreach loop

Tags: php, function, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array of days of the week, with each day having hours of the day (the whole array represents the schedule of a part-time employee):

```
Array
    (
        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15
                [1] => 14
                [2] => 13
                [3] => 11
                [4] => 12
                [5] => 10
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 13
                [2] => 12
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 6
            )

    )
```

and I simply need to:

1. sort asc each sub-array (2nd dimension) - no need to maintain the numeric keys, values are integers
2. sort asc the 1st dimension and maintain the numeric, integer keys

ie:

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 12
                [2] => 13
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 6
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 11
                [2] => 12
                [3] => 13
                [4] => 14
                [5] => 15
            )

    )
```

Additional info:

1. only the keys of the 1st dimension and the values of the 2nd dimension (and of course their association) are meaningful to my use-case
2. the 1st dimension can have at most 7 values, ranging from 1-7 (days of the week), and will have at least 1 value (1 day)
3. the 2nd dimension can have at most 24 values, ranging from 0-23 (hours of each day), and will have at least 1 value (1 hour per day)

I know I can do this with a `foreach` on the whole `ksort`ed array and `sort` each 2nd dimension array:

```
ksort($sched);
foreach ($sched as &$array) sort($array);
unset($array);
```

but I was hoping I could achieve this with native php array function(s) instead.

My search led me to try `array_multisort(array_values($array), array_keys($array), $array)` but I just can't make it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the best we can do:

```
ksort($arr);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
  array_multisort($arr[$k]);
```

Comment: ok, i don't know what happened to the other answers here, but they're gone! anyways, i chose this one for EXACTLY answering my question, but in the end i just did `sort` instead of `array_multisort` in this bit. thanks, @bsdnoobz

Comment: array_multisort with only one array is completely useless, I'd say. It is the same as using `sort($arr[$k])` - and thats what the original poster started with.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, you really have TWO sorting tasks to fulfill. The first is to sort the outer array by key. The second is to sort the inner arrays by value. Both sorting is independent from each other.

The best solution is the one you already found. array_multisort() will not help you, because that is made for sorting that actually *depends* on each other, like "sort by last name - if equal, sort by first name". But it should really be avoided, because defining a sorting function and using `usort()` and friends much better communicates what you are actually sorting.

Answer (score -1):

TRY following line

```
array_multisort(array_values($array), array_keys($array), ksort($array))
```

This may raise a warning but you can avoid it by **error_reporting(0)** if it really resolve the issue.

Comment: Coding something that needs to avoid warnings should never be done. Fix the problem instead.